# Modify a numeric value only in dicts where it exists (from within a JSON list)

Tags: json, numbers, jq

Simplified JSON file looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "key1": 1,
    "key2": "2"
  },
  {
    "key3": "3",
    "key4": 4
  }
]
```

I have no problem with reading numeric values from it.

```
jq ".[].\"key1\" |numbers" jsonfile
1
```

But I could not figure out how to modify them. This is what I tried:

```
jq ".[].\"key1\" -1 |numbers" jsonfile
0
jq: error (at jsonstr:1): null (null) and number (1) cannot be subtracted
```

`null` is coming from the second item, which causes the error above.

```
jq ".[].\"key1\"" jsonfile
1
null
```

Thing what I want is

```
[
  {
    "key1": 0,
    "key2": "2"
  },
  {
    "key3": "3",
    "key4": 4
  }
]
```

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. Select numbers before applying the change, not after.

```
(.[].key1 | numbers) -= 1
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/QvVeUpMeZr)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update the value in place, the simplest solution to the immediate problem would probably be:

```
   .[0].key1 += -1
```

or if counting keystrokes is very important in your assessment of simplicity:

```
   .[0].key1 -= 1
```

If you wanted to output the adjusted values of all numeric `.key1` values, you could go with:

```
.[] | .key1? | numbers - 1
```

The nature of the general problem being asked is unclear from the question, but if for example you wanted to update all occurrences of numeric `key1` values in the top-level objects in the array, you could go with:

```
.[] |= if (.key1|type) == "number" then .key1 += -1 else . end
```

This of course assumes the array items are all objects; if they are not, you could easily adapt the above accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to subtract 1 from `key1`, but leave all other values the same, that might look like:

```
jq '.[] |= if .key1? != null then .key1 = .key1 - 1 else . end'
```

You don't need `| numbers` anywhere, insofar as in your input, the only values that exist for `key1` are *already* numeric.

Answer (score 0):

To check whether a dictionary has a certain key, you can use the [`has(key)`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#has(key)) function. From there on, you can use a regular [if-then-else](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#if-then-else) block to alter the dictionary (subtract 1 from the value associated with `key1`) if the condition is true or leave it unchanged if the condition is not met.

```
jq '.[] |= if has("key1") then .key1 = .key1 - 1 else . end '
```

I also learned something new (for me) from [@Charles Duffy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65566618/827519) :

The first transformation was [`.[]`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Array/ObjectValueIterator:.%5B%5D) which helped to iterate over all items in the array. There's a difference here between using [`|=`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Update-assignment:%7C=) and [`|`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Pipe:%7C) : using the first one will update the values in the original input, while the second one in this case would unroll the array, and print the individual array elements.